Issues with Tooltip and Zoom in LightningChartJS Heatmap Using Logarithmic X-Axis
I am using LightningChartJS to create a heatmap that mimics a MatLab chart. Since the chart requires a logarithmic x-axis, I am using a workaround where the default linear x-axis is hidden (xAxis.setVisible(false)) and a logarithmic x-axis is added. However, I am encountering a couple of issues:

Tooltip Display Issue: The tooltip, which displays data when the user hovers over the heatmap, shows values for the default (hidden) linear x-axis instead of the logarithmic x-axis. How can I modify the tooltip to display values based on the logarithmic axis?


Zoom/Scroll Functionality Issue: Since the heatmap is attached to the invisible default linear x-axis, user interactions like zooming or scrolling on the logarithmic x-axis do not affect the heatmap's view. Is there a way to link the zoom/scroll of the logarithmic axis directly to the heatmap so that these interactions are reflected in the heatmap display?


Additionally, I've linked a GIF below that shows the issue with zooming and scrolling. The file is a bit large, hence hosted externally:
on google drive
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1qHSzwl1QkQpwCGd-rGlVsLdCiADC8Nqa/view?usp=sharing
Any insights or solutions would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you!
code
import { useEffect, useRef } from "react";
import {
  ColorRGBA,
  lightningChart,
  emptyLine,
  LUT,
  PalettedFill,
} from "@arction/lcjs";

export const HEATMAP_COLORS = [
  [92, 14, 10],
  [117, 9, 9],
  [133, 2, 7],
  [145, 0, 5],
  [150, 0, 2],
  [148, 2, 2],
  [148, 4, 3],
  [150, 6, 5],
  [152, 6, 6],
  [159, 5, 7],
  [164, 3, 8],
  [175, 4, 13],
  [178, 2, 15],
  [11, 3, 187],
  [10, 3, 181],
  [7, 2, 164],
  [5, 3, 166],
  [5, 2, 167],
  [7, 1, 169],
  [7, 2, 164],
  [4, 0, 147],
  [12, 10, 133],
];

export const CreateColorSteps = (minPSDVal: number, maxPSDVal: number) => {
  const colorSteps = [];
  for (let index = 0; index < HEATMAP_COLORS.length; index++) {
    const color = HEATMAP_COLORS[HEATMAP_COLORS.length - 1 - index];
    const clr = ColorRGBA(color[0], color[1], color[2]);
    const value =
      minPSDVal +
      (maxPSDVal - minPSDVal) * (index / (HEATMAP_COLORS.length - 1));
    const label =
      index === HEATMAP_COLORS.length - 1 ||
      index === Math.floor((HEATMAP_COLORS.length - 1) / 2) ||
      index === 0
        ? value.toFixed(1)
        : "";
    colorSteps.push({
      value: value,
      color: clr,
      label: label,
    });
  }
  console.log(colorSteps.length);
  return colorSteps;
};

function App() {
  const heatmapSeriesRef = useRef(null);
  const chartRef = useRef(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    const lc = lightningChart({});
    const dashboard = lc.Dashboard({
      numberOfColumns: 1,
      numberOfRows: 1,
      container: "lc",
    });
    const chart = dashboard.createChartXY({ columnIndex: 0, rowIndex: 0 });
    chart.getDefaultAxisX().setVisible(false);
    const logXAxis = chart
      .addAxisX({
        type: "logarithmic",
        base: 10,
      })
      .setInterval({
        start: 3,
        end: 500,
      });
    const axis = chart.getDefaultAxisY();
    axis.setInterval({ start: 0, end: 40 });

    const heatmapSeries = chart
      .addHeatmapGridSeries({
        xAxis: chart.getDefaultAxisX(),
        columns: 901,
        rows: 500,
        dataOrder: "rows",
        start: { x: 3, y: 20 },
        end: { x: 25, y: 25 },
      })
      .setWireframeStyle(emptyLine)
      .setIntensityInterpolation("bilinear");

    heatmapSeries.setCursorResultTableFormatter((builder, series, sample) =>
      builder
        .addRow(`Y is : ${series.axisY.formatValue(sample.y)}`)
        .addRow(`X  is not the log = ${sample.x.toFixed(1)}`)
        .addRow(`Intensity = ${sample.intensity}`)
    );

    chartRef.current = chart;
    heatmapSeriesRef.current = heatmapSeries;

    return () => {
      dashboard.dispose();
    };
  }, []);

  const expandHeatmap = () => {
    if (heatmapSeriesRef.current && chartRef.current) {
      heatmapSeriesRef.current.dispose();
      // heatmapSeriesRef.current.clear(); // need to ask Nilo how to use clear instead, works weird
      const newHeatmapSeries = chartRef.current
        .addHeatmapGridSeries({
          columns: 901,
          rows: 1000,
          dataOrder: "rows",
          start: { x: 0, y: 15 },
          end: { x: 25, y: 25 },
        })
        .setWireframeStyle(emptyLine)
        .setIntensityInterpolation("bilinear");

      const bigArray = [];
      for (let i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
        const arr = [];
        for (let j = 0; j < 901; j++) {
          // Scale the index so that the sine peaks at index 700
          let x = (Math.PI * j) / 1400; // 1400 is twice the peak index (700)
          arr.push(Math.sin(x));
        }
        bigArray.push(arr);
      }

      let minVal = bigArray[0][0];
      let maxVal = bigArray[0][0];

      for (const rowPSD of bigArray) {
        for (const value of rowPSD) {
          if (value < minVal) minVal = value;
          if (value > maxVal) maxVal = value;
        }
      }

      newHeatmapSeries.invalidateIntensityValues(bigArray);

      const colorSteps = CreateColorSteps(minVal, maxVal);
      const lut = new LUT({
        steps: colorSteps,
        interpolate: true,
      });
      newHeatmapSeries.setFillStyle(new PalettedFill({ lut }));

      newHeatmapSeries.invalidateIntensityValues(bigArray);

      heatmapSeriesRef.current = newHeatmapSeries;
    }
  };

  return (
    <>
      <button onClick={expandHeatmap}>expand heatmap</button>
      <div id="lc" style={{ width: "500px", height: "500px" }}></div>;
    </>
  );
}

export default App;


